# Can I install a shower surround over the flange?

Tags: shower, installation

[image][image]So I've really messed up. I'm at the tail end of finishing off our basement and I realized that my flange for my shower base is outside my backer board. Flooring is laid and the walls were built up to the base allowing 1/2" for backer board all the way around. I've even hooked the drain up, set the mortar and glued everything. This was found when we were installing the surround panels because I got in too much of a hurry.

Is it bad to just go ahead and install the surround over the flange or is that going to cause me issues down the road? I guess another option would be to buy another layer of backer board to go around the whole thing?

Tearing this all out isn't an option.

Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [edit] to add pictures... that would be helpful. Consider taking the [tour] as well.

Comment: Hard to say knowing nothing about your hardware. What are "surround panels"? Please revise your post to provide enough information for us to answer.

Comment: A picture would be nice.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and I appreciate people letting me know I need to add more information. The surround is Flexstone brand panels that are intended to be applied with adhesive. I've screwed the flange to the wall, but since there are only a few studs, the flange doesn't suck up to the wall (hence why you put the flange behind the backer board). I've included some pictures of what the panels look like along with the base. When I get home, I'm hoping to post another picture of the actual problem.